# Mapping columns from one dataframe to another based on few conditions to consider one mapping out of multiple mappings present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have two dataframes A and B with a common column 'label'.I would like to create a new column 'Map' in dataframe A which consist of corresponding mapping from dataframe B.

Required Conditions :

1. With every mapping, increment a variable count by 1 (which would be compared to the 'Capacity' column in dataframe B)
2. The mapping of 'label' column should be done based on higher value of 'Num' column from  dataframe B. Also if the count becomes greater than 'Capacity' for next assignment, assign second best 'Num' mapping and so on.
3. If there's no available mapping OR the 'Capacity' for available mapping is full  then update the 'Map' as None

Dataframe A

```
   Id     label
    1      1       
    2      1       
    3      1     
    4      2 
    5      2     
    6      3
    7      3
```

Dataframe B

```
label   Capacity  Map Num
  1        1       A   0.1
  1        2       B   0.2
  2        2       C   0.3
  3        1       D   0.2
```

Expected Output Dataframe

```
   Id     label   Map
    1      1       B
    2      1       B
    3      1       A
    4      2       C
    5      2       C
    6      3       D
    7      3       None
```

Any pythonic way for this. I would appreciate some explanation on the code.

Comment: has any of the answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to duplicate the mentioned data frames. My approach is to first sort the "B" dataframe by "Num" first and then by "capacity". Then looping over the "A" dataframe, I was able to select the correct "map" label and decrement the available capacity as well.

```
import pandas as pd
        
        dfA = pd.DataFrame()
        dfA["Id"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7

]
    dfA["label"] = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3]
    
    dfB = pd.DataFrame()
    dfB["label"] = [1,1,2,3]
    dfB["cap"] = [1,2,2,1]
    dfB["map"] = ["A","B","C","D"]
    dfB["num"] = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2]
     
    
    test = dfB.copy()
    test = test.sort_values(by = ['num', "cap"], ascending = [False, False], na_position = 'first')
    
    
    map_list = []
    
    for index, row in dfA.iterrows():
        currLabel = row["label"]
        x = test.loc[test['label'] == currLabel]
        if len(x):
            foundMap = False
            for i,r in x.iterrows():
                if r["cap"] > 0:
                    test.at[i,"cap"] = r["cap"]-1
                    map_list.append(r["map"])
                    foundMap = True
                    break
            if not foundMap:
                map_list.append(None)
        else:
            map_list.append(None)
            
    dfA["map"] = map_list
```

Instead of creating a copy of dfB, you could also create a new column in dfB, which will maintain the realtime capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your initial dataframes are:

```
>>> dfa
   Id  label
0   1      1
1   2      1
2   3      1
3   4      2
4   5      2
5   6      3
6   7      3

>>> dfb
   label  Capacity Map  Num
0      1         1   A  0.1
1      1         2   B  0.2
2      2         2   C  0.3
3      3         1   D  0.2
```

First, start with refactoring a bit the dataframes. We calculate the [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for dfa and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) for dfb. This gives us how many rows can be allocated in the order of the map with a cumulated limit.

```
dfa['count'] = dfa.groupby('label').cumcount()+1

dfb.sort_values(by='Num', ascending=False, inplace=True)
dfb['count'] = dfb.groupby('label')['Capacity'].cumsum()
```

Then we define a custom function to do the mapping. The try/except block handles the case where no rows are available to map and the function will return `None`

```
def custom_map(s):
    try:
        return (dfb[dfb['label'].eq(s['label']) &  # same label
                    dfb['count'].ge(s['count'])    # within capacity
                   ].iloc[0]['Map'])               # take first element
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Finally, we map the values using:

```
dfa['Map'] = dfa.apply(custom_map, axis=1)
dfa.drop('count', axis=1)
```

output:

```
   Id  label   Map
0   1      1     B
1   2      1     B
2   3      1     A
3   4      2     C
4   5      2     C
5   6      3     D
6   7      3  None
```